# what server specs do i need to host a online movie streaming website?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails

Im developing a website that going to let users stream online movies and im looking for a server to start with.
im guessing that for start i dont need something fancy but its still need to be good cause streaming movies are pretty heavy so i would be thankful if you could help me with the specs of the server.(the videos are not hosted on my website)
thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear; if the videos are not on your site how do you intend to stream them - also have you searched on this site as this kind of question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very vague question, how many monthly users will you get? How heavy is each request? (Does it just lookup one record from a database and return some content, or does it do hundreds of SQL joins?) How burstable will your users be? (I.E. will you get 10 hits one day and 10,000 the next).

You won't be able to get a definitive answer unless you can provide more info, we can only give you pointers.

If you're not sure about this I'd suggest AWS EC2/Rackspace Cloud with auto-scaling, then after a few months and a bit of monitoring you'll have a better idea what you need so you can move to physical boxes.